# Oracle 11g sql to join table for a specific value against all values of other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a join on two tables , for matched values it
should return matched records, But when it has a specific value (e.g. `All`) the
join should  return join against all records Example below

```
Payment
----  
Cash  
Card  
Wallet 



Bill_Settlement
----- 
Cash  
Card    
Wallet  
All
```

**Output**

```
Bill  payment
-----  ------------
 
Cash   Cash  
Card   Card    
Wallet Wallet  
All    Cash  
All    Card  
All    Wallet
```

Comment: Why your output includes both cases ? could you format the question anyway in a good way ?

Comment: I think no need to fix to a constant value(`All`) in order to bring matched and unmatched together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two queries, the first one is a simple *equi join*.

The second query makes a join while constraining only your *special values*, i.e. *all* rows from other table are joined.

The result is connected with `UNION ALL` - as the expectation is that the *special values* are *not* on the `Payment` table and you need not to remove duplicates.

```
select *
from Payment p
join Bill_Settlement b
on p.payment = b.bill
union all
select *
from Payment p
join Bill_Settlement b
on b.bill in ('All')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understantd your question correctly, but to get required output, you can use standard (LEFT OUTER) JOIN with ON condition using DECODE or CASE function like this:

```
   WITH
      Payment AS (
         SELECT 'Cash'   AS payment FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Card'   AS payment FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Wallet' AS payment FROM DUAL
      )
      ,Bill_Settlement AS (
         SELECT 'Cash'   AS bill FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Card'   AS bill FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Wallet' AS bill FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'All' AS bill FROM DUAL
      )
      -- Main query
      SELECT T2.bill
            ,T1.payment
        FROM Bill_Settlement T2
        LEFT JOIN Payment T1 -- It should work with INNER JOIN as well
          ON T2.bill = DECODE(T2.bill, 'All', T2.bill, T1.payment) 
          -- Instead of DECODE function you can use standard CASE statement: CASE WHEN (T2.bill = 'All') THEN T2.bill ELSE T1.payment END
      ;
```

In this case it does standard filter, but for value 'All' it skips the ON statement and (in this example) provide a cartezian product.

You might need to extend ON statement with another condition(s) in order to avoid malfunction for specific values or biggere data-set(s).

Let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Matched and unmatched cases might be brought together **without** fixing a spesific value (`All`) through applying `OUTER(LEFT or FULL or RIGHT provided that the order of tables is changed)` and `CROSS JOIN`s recursively :

```
SELECT bill, p2.payment
  FROM (SELECT bill, payment
          FROM Bill_Settlement
          LEFT JOIN Payment 
            ON bill = payment) p1
 CROSS JOIN Payment p2
 WHERE p2.payment = p1.payment AND p1.payment IS NOT NULL
    OR p1.payment IS NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=640ec386b741ce2cd86406496cd5d5e4)</kbd>